# DRF get_permissions doesn't appear to work correctly

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to configure permissions for my custom `User` model and I'm using a Viewset to run CRUD operations for the model. Depending on the operation, I need to set different permission requirements such that:

- anyone can `create` a new `User` instance
- only owners or admins can `retrieve` or `update` users

For some reason, when I define the `get_permissions` method inside my class, like so:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == 'create':
        return [AllowAny(),]

    elif self.action == 'me':
        return [IsAuthenticated(),]

    return [IsAuthenticated(), IsOwnerOrAdmin()]
```

but when I navigate to `/api/v1/users/`, the DRF explorer doesn't show the form to create a new `User` and gives me a 403 error. On the flipside, when I comment this function out, I *can* see form properly, but obviously can't use it that way.

For reference, my custom `IsOwnerOrAdmin` permissions class looks like:

```
class IsOwnerOrAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):

    @staticmethod
    def _is_admin(request):
        return request.user.is_superuser

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            is_owner = str(request.user.id) == view.kwargs.get('pk')

            return is_owner or self._is_admin(request)

        # if request.user.uuid is not there (i.e. AnonymousUser)
        except AttributeError:
            return False
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

```
class IsOwnerOrAdmin(BasePermission):
    @staticmethod
    def _is_admin(request):
        return request.user.is_superuser

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user or self._is_admin(request)
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error. Tried this with both the existing has_permission method and alone, still nothing. Any other thoughts?